# UML use case diagram, different actor for viewer?

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm wondering if my use case diagram is about right and if anyone could give me some pointers if it's not.

It's for an application where users can login (always required). When they login they see a list with posts which they can up or downvote (like reddit). When selecting a post they can place and delete(only their own) comments.

The user that's logged in can place posts when logged in, but also has a button to view posts they've already placed where they can be edited and deleted.

Finally there's an admin that can delete inappropriate posts and comments.

Am I supposed to define that users can only edit and delete their own posts and comments? If so, how do I do that? Perhaps a different actor?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of flaws in your UCs.

1. Login is not a UC at all (it does not add any value to the actor). It is a constraint you may apply to UCs.
2. Wrong username/pw is no UC, of course. It's some message that will pop up somewhere.
3. Register is a UC on it's own. Connect it directly to User.
4. Using generalization with UC is not a good idea since it will bring in a lot of stuff for discussion. Leave it at the `Manage` level and describe inside the UC what this means.
5. `<<include>>` is usually used the wrong way (namely for functional decomposition). And you are doing that too. So leave it away, concentrate on the basic UC `Manage comments` and connect that directly with the actor.

If for some reason you need to describe some order for UCs you can use pre-conditions inside the UCs.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you cannot model everything using use case diagram. A single UC is a set of action flows that provide a specific business result. You can provide details on limitations (e.g. condition that you can manage only your own comments) in a description of UC (either modelled by activity or sequence diagram or simply in a written description) but **not** on UC diagram.

As the commenting is optional in your system, definitely you've used incorrect relationship. *include* means that the included UC will be **always** executed when executing including UC. In your case this is up to a decision of a user which means you should use *extends* instead (and of course in this case the relationship is in the opposite direction). See 18.1.3.2 (second paragraph) and 18.1.3.3 (first paragraph). You can also find confirmation of that in almost any book about UML based analysis (e.g. Howard Podeswa's "UML for the business analyst" to name one)

Besides that I agree with the list of flaws given by Thomas Kilian.